# how to add source/javadoc classifiers to an unmanaged jar?

Tags: scala, sbt

in ENSIME we add the JDK `tools.jar` to the classpath as an `unmanagedJars`. However, I'd also like to attach the source zip that I've downloaded from http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/ as a `src` classifer, is there any way to do this?

There doesn't appear to be an `unmanagedClassifiersJars` key, so the only way I can think of doing this is by customising the `updateClassifiers` stage and returning a version of the `UpdateReport` containing the source jar. But this seems really hard, is there a convenience method for adding a file to the update report?